# applescript to move folders based on their name to a network folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to create an applescript that can be run periodically as an application to do some maintenance with folders.

For example:
there's 2 folders on the desktop. one is named "George Project" and the other named "Rocco project".

I need any folders, and their respective sub-folders, containing George, to be moved to a george folder on a network drive (/Volumes/AMT/George), and the same thing with any folders containing Rocco, etc.

All of these named folders would only be in 2 locations, so I'd like the script to check both locations for any folders containing these names and move them to the right place on the network.

So far, I've tried this script on my local drive, but it didn't actually move anything:

```
global theWatchedFolder
set theWatchedFolder to choose folder
on idle
    tell application "Finder"
        set theDetectedItems to every item of theWatchedFolder whose name contains "rocco"
        repeat with aDetectedItem in theDetectedItems
            move aDetectedItem to "/Users/Rocco/Test"
        end repeat
    end tell
    return 1
end idle
```

Answer (score 0):

1) in the move instruction you must use Finder path (User:Rocco:Test:) and not Unix path (/Users/Rocco/Test). Also the destination folder should be an alias, not a string

```
move aDetectedItem to ("Users:Rocco:Test:" as alias)
```

2) the return 1 will force your script to run only 1 second after. Certainly too fast. may be already every 30 seconds should be enough to not kill your system.

3) when source and destination are on different volumes (it seems to be the case), the move command does not "move" but but performs a copy. Your files will remain in the source folder, then your script will keep copying them to destination folder for ever. After successful move, you should delete them.

4) instead of using 'idle' handler, why are you not using a folder action script on your 2 desktop folders ? With "on adding item" handler, the script will run each time you add an item (file or folder) in the folder (one script for George Project and almost same for Rocco project). This script should look for all files/folders added, move them, and eventually delete them. Because only added item are process with this handler, you're not forced to delete already processed items.